# orientDB: error when startup second node on distributed nodes ,Quorum cannot be reached because there are no nodes available

Tags: orientdb

thanks!
I'm really trying to setup on 3 servers. For the purpose of an example, I'm
trying to setup a class "actor", with 3 clusters "actor_server74",
"actor_server75", and "actor_server76". My servers are called server74, server75, and
server76. I want the clusters arranged such that I have 2 copies of each
cluster, so if 1 node goes down I still have access to all the data, so for
example:

- server74 is master for actor_server74 and has a copy of actor_server75.
- server75 is master for actor_server75 and has a copy of actor_server76.
- server76 is master for actor_server76 and has a copy of actor_server74.

I've tried setting this up with the following steps:
1. Download OrientDB 2.1.15 Community and extract onto the 3 servers.
2. Delete the GratefulDeadConcerts database from the databases directory on each server.
3. Configure hazelcast.xml with tcp-ip instead of multi-cast and specifying the IP address of the 3 servers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <group>
        <name>root</name>
        <password>root</password>
    </group>
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="false">2434</port>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false">
                <multicast-group>224.0.0.1</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>2434</multicast-port>
            </multicast>
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <member>172.21.0.74:2434</member>
                <member>172.21.0.75:2434</member>
                <member>172.21.0.76:2434</member>
            </tcp-ip>
        </join>
    </network>
    <executor-service>
        <pool-size>16</pool-size>
    </executor-service>
</hazelcast>
```

4. Edit default-distributed-db-config.json on server74 as follows :
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8Qcs.jpg)
5. Start server74 with dserver.sh.
6. Create a database using console on server74:
   connect remote:localhost root root
   create database remote:localhost/testdb root root plocal graph
7. Create a class and rename the default cluster:
   create class actor extends v
   alter cluster actor name actor_server74
8. shutdown server74 with shutdown.sh
9. copy orientdb-community-2.1.15 from server74 to server75 and server76, and update the nodeName in config/orientdb-server-config.xml , server75 as follows:
10. startup server74 with dserver.sh

    ### 11. Startup server75 with dserver.sh, throw exception as follows.

---

```
2016-04-08 23:23:10:533 INFO  [server75] Saving distributed configuration file for database 'testdb' to: /data/server/orientdb-community-2.1.15/databases/testdb/distributed-config.json [OHazelcastPlugin]
2016-04-08 23:23:10:550 INFO  [server75] Publishing online status for database server75.testdb... [OHazelcastDistributedDatabase]
2016-04-08 23:23:10:556 INFO  [server75] received updated status server75.testdb=ONLINE [OHazelcastPlugin][server75] Error on starting distributed plugin
com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException: Quorum cannot be reached because there are no nodes available
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.calculateQuorum(OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.java:417)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.send2Nodes(OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.java:121)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.sendRequest(OHazelcastPlugin.java:358)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSyncCluster.replaceCluster(OCommandExecutorSQLSyncCluster.java:155)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.requestDatabase(OHazelcastPlugin.java:975)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.installDatabase(OHazelcastPlugin.java:906)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.installNewDatabases(OHazelcastPlugin.java:1484)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.startup(OHazelcastPlugin.java:175)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.registerPlugins(OServer.java:993)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:336)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:41)
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedStartupException: Error on starting distributed plugin
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.startup(OHazelcastPlugin.java:184)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.registerPlugins(OServer.java:993)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:336)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:41)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException: Quorum cannot be reached because there are no nodes available
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.calculateQuorum(OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.java:417)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.send2Nodes(OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.java:121)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.sendRequest(OHazelcastPlugin.java:358)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSyncCluster.replaceCluster(OCommandExecutorSQLSyncCluster.java:155)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.requestDatabase(OHazelcastPlugin.java:975)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.installDatabase(OHazelcastPlugin.java:906)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.installNewDatabases(OHazelcastPlugin.java:1484)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.startup(OHazelcastPlugin.java:175)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: 9. as follows :<handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="true" name="enabled"/>
                <parameter value="${ORIENTDB_HOME}/config/default-distributed-db-config.json" name="configuration.db.default"/>
                <parameter value="${ORIENTDB_HOME}/config/hazelcast.xml" name="configuration.hazelcast"/>
                <parameter value="server75" name="nodeName"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>

Comment: I tried with your configuration and I got your same exception.
Did you follow this guide http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Distributed-Configuration.html#default-distributed ?

Comment: @ Alessandro Rota  thank you! I follow the guide, and read 3 times .I don't know which part is wrong.

Comment: Please try it with 2.2.0-rc1